# Rails Migrations Change vs Up/Down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I completely understand the difference between the `up`/`down` methods and the `change` methods, but I don't understand why rails seems to generate one over the other.

I've just run the following command and gotten a `change` method:

```
rails generate migration AddUpdaterCreatorToRequest
```

About ten minutes ago I ran the following and got the `up` and `down` methods:

```
rails generate migration AddClientPrimaryEngineer
```

What gives? Both start with add (for a while I was wondering if there wasn't some NLP like stuff going on...) is it 'To' that's missing on the second to make it give me a `change` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Rails happens to successfully parse the migration name and it will be able to generate the code for you, it will use the `change` method. Otherwise it will just fallback to `up`/`down` methods and let you fill the pieces.

I think the second migration name should be *CreateClientPrimaryEngineer*.

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  Thanks.  Just as an FYI it seems that `AddPrimaryEngineerToClient` *does* create a change method.

Comment: Also, it doesn't generate any code for me when I do these migrations.  Just selects between create and up/down.

Comment: I am not able to test it out now... It will if you provide some column names, try to do something like "rails g migration add_name_to_users name:string". I usually use underscores so it reads better but it shouldn't matter... Also string type is the default so you can omit that.

Comment: Ahh, I'm doing it by hand, I find that I like my SQL better. But thanks for the help!